# Popular informal physics book containing a quote from Lewis Carroll

Tags: identification-request

It was a book from 1970s or 1980s about physics written in a popular informal way. It described relative motion by example of shooting an arrow from the back of a train, it described the Michelson-Morley experiment and it contained a quote from Lewis Carroll.

> But I was thinking of a plan
> To dye one's whiskers green,
> And always use so large a fan
> That they could not be seen.

Can you help me identify the book?

Originally my question was here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/where-to-ask-in-order-to-locate-a-book

Additional info: I think that it also contained a description about two lightbulbs inside a closed box and that the two lightbulbs are turned on, then the question is whether or not there will be a shadow from any of the lightbulbs.

I think I remember that the cover was white and green and that it was quite easy reading and popular science because I could understand it even though I did not know calculus at the time but it did explain relativity with words and examples instead of mathematical equations.

Comment: As they say in the comments to the answer, it is really hard to identify the book having that little information. My guess would be Martin Gardner's Relativity for Millions (or Relativity Simply Explained). First published in 1967. It doesn't talk arrow and train, but rather bullet and jet. And it does feature Lewis Carrol quote.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you're talking about is [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0jmZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=But+I+was+thinking+of+a+plan%0ATo+dye+one%27s+whiskers+green,%0AAnd+always+use+so+large+a+fan%0AThat+they+could+not+be+seen.&source=bl&ots=YNIJdRAM7n&sig=ACfU3U1p6pKrXKbSOUHSnGD_szuusyJrGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWrZup8_TpAhU5ZhUIHZC3BMIQ6AEwBXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=But%20I%20was%20thinking%20of%20a%20plan%20To%20dye%20one's%20whiskers%20green%2C%20And%20always%20use%20so%20large%20a%20fan%20That%20they%20could%20not%20be%20seen.&f=false).

**The nature of the physical world: THE GIFFORD LECTURES 1927** by Sir Arthur Eddington.

I have to admit I've found it by googling.

Comment: It could be the one especially since the poem is included but it is not recognizable as the one I have vague memories about.

Comment: Well, if you scroll to previous page (I mean, under the link) it mentions Michelson-Morley experiment. So, I reckon, there can hardly be two books in the world having both "criteria".)) How long has it been since you read it?

Comment: Most popular physics books mention the Michelson–Morley experiment, and a large proportion of them contain Lewis Carroll quotations. What about shooting an arrow from the back of a train?

Comment: @user14111 You are absolutely right. Could the OP provide any additional information they have, please? For example, the country where the book was printed? The colour of the cover?

Comment: Does your Eddington book have anything about shooting an arrow from a train?

Comment: @user14111 I wish I knew :) As I said in my "answer" - I googled up the book, I haven't read it. And don't really have the time to read it at the moment.

Comment: @tum_ It was in the 1980s that I read it. 1985 give or take a few years.

Answer (score 2):

Was it Martin Gardner's book *Relativity for the Million*? This appeared originally in 1962, although it has been updated and retitled twice since then. Google Books shows that the latest version, *Relativity Simply Explained* (1997) contains the Lewis Carroll poem.